# Web container in JBoss 6 and other queries

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x, servlet-3.0, jboss-web

1. What is the default web container in JBoss 6? If what I read was correct, the answer to this question should be JBoss Web (the custom built web container based on Apache Tomcat).
2. Am I correct in understanding that JBoss 6 completely supports the Servlet 3.0 specification?
3. I want to make my web application deployed on my machine in JBoss 6 accessible to other machines on my network (LAN). How can I do this? Will passing -b 0.0.0.0 as a start argument suffice? What if I want to make my application accessible all over the internet (I don't really want to do this, but I am interested in knowing how)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. yes
2. yes since milestone 2
3. yes, -b 0.0.0.0 -- all over the internet: have your router forward port 80 or 8080 to your machine running AS 6